# Odd PS CS5.5 problem: can't right click, drag, or use the keyboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The strangest Photoshop problem I've ever had just came up...  I all of a sudden cannot right click, click and drag, use modifier keys (I can push B for brush, but can't say Ctrl-O for open) or long click (I cannot select the secondary tools such as switching between the paint bucket and gradient tools).

I tried deleting my user prefs (had to do it manually because modifier keys aren't working so no Ctrl-Alt-Shift), and that works for literally a few seconds and then the problem reappears.  I can't recall doing anything strange to trigger the error; I was using the program just fine and suddenly I couldn't do anything I needed to.  I'm having no issues with other software, even other Adobe software.  I'm running CS5.5 on Windows 7 Pro.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running Synergy is a common cause of this.

Switching synergy to application mode instead of service mode fixes this.

Comment: That must have been the problem -- I remember playing around with Synergy back then (I had never used it before that). I actually just reinstalled Windows after a while and never put Synergy back on, and now PS is running fine.

Comment: Thank God for Google sending me here to your answer. Solved my problem with Adobe and Synergy.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to delete preferences from inside Photoshop, so the modifier key problem *in Photoshop* should have no effect. (You have to hold down Ctl, Alt and Shift before Photoshop starts, and answer "Yes" to the dialog. I'm assuming that's what you did.)

The next echelon of handling is to uninstall Photoshop, then reinstall Photoshop from the DVD or your downloaded suite installer. Before you go that far, you might want to double-check that your mouse and video (yes, GPU drivers can have some weird effects) drivers are fully up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I eventually had to uninstall it, but whatever works...

Comment: Glad to know things are back to normal. "Whatever works" is right!